# Error: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views on Android app

Tags: java, android, json, multithreading, listview

I have an activity that populates a `ListView`. This works correctly. Now, I want to populate the `ListView` using `JSON` text from a `PHP` script. I have an adapter for my objects (Locations) and I want to add a location for each `JSON` object. But when I call the method to add the `JSON` data to the adapter (`getData()`), I get:

`Error Parsing Data android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks

Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ArrayList<Location> arrayOfLocations;
LocationAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Construct the data source
    arrayOfLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();

    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    adapter = new LocationAdapter(this, arrayOfLocations);

    adapter.add(new Location(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Fruit Stand",
            "We have the freshest fruit in the whole world!", "2 miles",
            "8-5 mon-sat\nclosed sun"));

    getData();

    // Attach the adapter to a ListView
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    View header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.listview_header, null);
    listView.addHeaderView(header);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void getData() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String result = "";
            InputStream isr = null;
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://10.0.0.9/examples.php"); // YOUR PHP SCRIPT
                                                            // ADDRESS
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                isr = entity.getContent();
                // resultView.setText("connected");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }
            // convert response to string
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                isr.close();

                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // parse json data
            try {
                String s = "";
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    s = s + "Title : " + json.getString("PlaceTitle")
                            + " Details: " + json.getString("PlaceDetails")
                            + "\n" + "Distance : "
                            + json.getString("PlaceDistance") + "\n\n";
                    adapter.add(new Location(R.drawable.ic_launcher, json
                            .getString("PlaceTitle"), json
                            .getString("PlaceDetails"), json
                            .getString("PlaceDistance"), "9-6"));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}

}
```

logcat:

```
05-29 15:56:47.353: D/OpenGLRenderer(19595): Enabling debug mode 0
05-29 15:59:09.095: D/libEGL(19832): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
05-29 15:59:09.119: D/libEGL(19832): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
05-29 15:59:09.127: D/libEGL(19832): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
05-29 15:59:09.213: D/OpenGLRenderer(19832): Enabling debug mode 0
05-29 15:59:09.236: I/Choreographer(19832): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-29 15:59:09.853: E/log_tag(19832): Error Parsing Data android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're adding to your `Adapter` from a background thread. This will trigger a redraw of all of the visible Views in the list so that it can display the latest data from the adapter. However, Views can only be modified from the UI thread. One quick solution would be to wrap the addition in a runnable and post it to the UI thread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        adapter.add(new Location(R.drawable.ic_launcher, 
                json.getString("PlaceTitle"), 
                json.getString("PlaceDetails"), 
                json.getString("PlaceDistance"), "9-6"));
    }
});
```

I don't really recommend this. You could use either an `AsyncTask` or a `Service` that downloads and parses the response into a `List<Location>` with all of the results, and then after it completes, and you're back on the UI thread, add all of the results at once.